# How Can I Detect If There are Secondary Objects in an Image

Tags: python, opencv

I am looking for a way to detect if there are secondary objects in an image or if the image just has the one main object. I've done a bit of research, but I haven't been able to find anything quite like what I am looking for.

An example image would be:

[image]

The main object being the two detergent bottles since they overlap and the secondary object would be the "2 pack" pop up bubble in the top right. I would expect this image to return something like: "This image has secondary objects" or a count of the objects.

Comment: Threshold the image so that anything not white is black. Invert the result. Get the external contours. If more than one, then you have secondary objects.

Comment: @fmw42 how do I have it count the external contours?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV

- Read the input
- Convert to gray and invert
- OTSU threshold
- Morphology close
- Get external contours
- Draw contours on image
- Count contours
- Print messages
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("tide.jpg")

# convert img to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# invert gray image
gray = 255 - gray

# threshold gray image
#thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# apply morphology close
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 5))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# Get contours
cntrs = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1]
result = img.copy()
for c in cntrs:
    cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (0,0,255), 1)

count = len(cntrs)
print("")
print("count =",count)

print("")

if count > 1:
    print("This image has secondary objects")
else:
    print("This image has primary object only")

# write results to disk
cv2.imwrite("tide_thresh.png", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("tide_morph.png", morph)
cv2.imwrite("tide_object_contours.png", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Thresholded image:

[image]

Morphology close image:

[image]

Contours on image:

[image]

Count of contours and messages:

```
count = 2

This image has secondary objects
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to put this together. It definitely works for that sample image, but when I ran  [another image](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81eXaryGgeL._SY355_.jpg) through that I would want to come back with a count of 1 it didn't seem to do so well. That one came back with a count of 43 for me. I am still trying to understand the counting of contours to better understand how to make it work for a variety of image types.

Comment: Post a link to that other image. Perhaps it has noise or was a jpg and the threshold left spots that are considered as other objects.

Comment: If this was helpful, please consider up-voting it.

Comment: I linked the other image in my initial comment, the link is: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81eXaryGgeL._SY355_.jpg. I ended up finding another script that seemed to work more accurately for my test images, but still not perfect. You can see that in the answer I posted.

Comment: That is because the bottles are too close in white color to the background. So Otsu thresholding is not working well. So you would have to use normal thresholding and find a reasonable threshold value. In my script, replace the threshold command with the following and it works fine. `thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 16, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]`

Comment: @Cole maybe you can try to implement [Color Quantization via K-means](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/07/color-quantization-opencv-using-k-means-clustering/) and see if that improves the segmentation between foreground objects.

Comment: @fmw42 Additional question, is it possible to detect if there is text in the contours and only count the contour at that point? I am trying to find a way where an image like these [apples](https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/106-1064649_two-apples-png-transparent-png.png) could be differentiated from the original detergent image. My main goal here is to be able to find images that have pop-out bubbles with text in them like the intial image which would be considered bad, but the picture of apples would be considered good.

Comment: I am not an expert on text processing. So I do not have an answer for you in that regard.

Comment: @fmw42 No worries! This works great, so it would just be an additional check I need to run before this one. I will figure something out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can try to use pytesseract on each region and see if it detects text.

Comment: @fmw42 that is actually what I ended up doing for text detection and it works pretty well so far. I also ran into another issue for images that have products that aren't fully centered and touch the edges being read as multiple objects, so working on a fix for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Following @fmw42's advice, I did a bit of research and found a script that worked well after a little bit of tinkering:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys


img = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1], cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

#convert img to grey
img_grey = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#set a thresh
thresh = 230
#get threshold image
ret,thresh_img = cv2.threshold(img_grey, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
#find contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#create an empty image for contours
# img_contours = np.zeros(img.shape)
img_contours = np.zeros_like(img)
# draw the contours on the empty image
cv2.drawContours(img_contours, contours, -1, 255, 3)
#save image
cv2.imshow('contours',img_contours)
# Wait indefinitely until you push a key.  Once you do, close the windows

print len(contours)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My main issue was the threshold setting and I found that 230 worked best with my sample images, although it still is not perfect. I'm hoping there is a better way or something I can add to this.

[this image](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81eXaryGgeL._SY355_.jpg) returned 1 as expected, but [my initial test image](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81TePlCvUFL._AC_SX466_PIbundle-2,TopRight,0,0_SH20_.jpg) returns 3 at this threshold setting when I would expect 2. At 200 thresh it returns 2, but I was willing to compromise because the main thing I need to know is if it is more than 1.